# What data type is best for storing comments in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, types

What is an effective datatype in SQL 2005 to store a comments field?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the comment will always fit in 8000 chars then `varchar(8000)` (or `nvarchar(4000)`).

Otherwise a `varchar(max)`

Answer (score 1):

That depends on whether or not you limit the comment length. On SO, `nvarchar(600)` does it. On a blog, you probably want `nvarchar(max)`.

Comment: `varchar(max)` or `nvarchar(max)` would be more appropriate than `text` on SQL Server 2005.

Comment: @John: You're right, I always forget that `text` was deprecated.

Comment: i think you always want a reasonable upper bound for any text field. nvarchar(max) on a public field opens your db for abuse.

Comment: @psasik: And if your reasonable upper bound is OVER 9000?!

Answer (score 0):

Apparently SQL 2005 only supports:

varchar(max) Variable-length non-Unicode data with a maximum length of 2^31 characters.

If you need unicode character strings,

nvarchar(max) Variable-length Unicode data with a maximum length of 2^30 characters.

text is also supported as a datatype.  Use this site if you need more reference:

http://www.teratrax.com/sql_guide/data_types/sql_server_data_types.html

Comment: text will be deprecated in later versions and is nothing like as flexible as varchar(max).

Comment: This was mentioned for Eric's answer below too